# Function that checks if a substring is within another string in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I need to write a function that check if a substring is within another string by using list comprehensions.

I'm using `drop` create a list of strings from a string to use `isPrefixOf` to compare the list of strings created to the substring.

Here is my code:

```hs
contains :: String -> String -> Bool
contains str substr = isPrefixOf substr (check str)
    where
    check :: String -> [String]
    check str
        |str==[]   = []
        |otherwise = [drop x str | x <- [0..length(str)-1]]
```

However, I get this error:

```
Tutorial2.hs:163:42: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
      Expected type: [Char]
        Actual type: [String]
    * In the second argument of `isPrefixOf', namely `(check str)'
      In the expression: isPrefixOf substr (check str)
      In an equation for `contains':
          contains str substr
            = isPrefixOf substr (check str)
            where
                check :: String -> [String]
                check str
                  | str == [] = []
                  | otherwise = [drop x str | x <- [0 .. length (str) - 1]]
    |
163 | contains str substr = isPrefixOf substr (check str)
```

I want to understand why I am getting this error and how do I fix it. I'm assuming it's because I'm giving isPrefixOf a list of a list [[a]] with my function check str and it doesn't take that?

Comment: isPrefixOf expects two strings, not a string and a list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`IsPrefixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf) expects two lists of the same type (and that type should be a member of the `Eq` typeclass), so two `String`s for example, since a `String` is a list of `Char`s.

You however provide a `String` (the `substr`), and a list of `String`s (the `check str` has as type `[String]`). This thus will not typecheck. Furthermore using `drop` multiple times will make `check str` run in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* which is not efficient.

You can make use of [**`any :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf) to check if a predicate is satisfied for any element in a foldable, for example a list. We can furthermore make use of [**`tails :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) to obtain all the tails of a list (including the full list) in a more efficient manner:

```
import Data.List(isPrefixOf, tails)

contains :: String -> String -> Bool
contains str substr = any (isPrefixOf substr) (tails str)
```

we can further generalize this to work with a list of any type `a` that is a member of the `Eq` typeclass:

```
import Data.List(isPrefixOf, tails)

contains :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
contains str substr = any (isPrefixOf substr) (tails str)
```

We can also make the function *point-free* by making use of [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip)  and [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.):

```
import Data.List(isPrefixOf, tails)

contains :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
contains = flip (any . isPrefixOf) . tails
```

Comment: Although I really appreciate your answer and expalanations, I'm afraid they're a bit lost on me since I am still a beginner in Haskell.

However I do understand that I am giving `isPrefixOf` a wrong type with `check str`, so I'm wondering how I can go about giving it the correct type while retaining most of my code (at the very least one list comprehension)

Comment: @straw6erry He's saying that `tails str` does the same thing as your `check str`, but more efficiently. Also `isPrefixOf substr ...list...` won't work, but `any (isPrefixOf substr) ...list...` will work.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Ahhhh I see, thank you for explaining further. Thanks all for helping!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `isPrefixOf` expects one `String`, but your `check` returns a list of strings (`[String]`).

The fix is to wrap the `isPrefixOf` in `any`, which maps the function over the whole list:

```
contains :: String -> String -> Bool
contains str substr = any (isPrefixOf substr) (check str)
    where
    check :: String -> [String]
    -- ...
```

Note that `check` is equivalent to the built-in `tails` (technically it should be `length str`, not `length str - 1`, but that doesn't matter in this case), so if we make that substitution we arrive at [Willem's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234460/617159):

```
contains :: String -> String -> Bool
contains str substr = any (isPrefixOf substr) (tails str)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way (compared to the answers posted so far) to check if a string is a substring of another. You can use the isInfixOf function in Data.List.

Here is the signature:

```
isInfixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

The first argument is the substring, and the second argument is the larger string in which you want to check for the substring.

[Here is the documentation :)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isInfixOf)